# Sample Distribution For Entry At Next Step

Tags: r, sample

```
set.seed(1)
data1 = data.frame(t(replicate(20, diff(c(0, sort(runif(2)), 1)))))
names(data1)=c("Repeat", "Advance", "GoBack")
data1$Grade = rep(1:10,2)
data1$Size=rep(0:1,each=10)

data2 = data.frame("Student" = c(1:1000),
                   "Grade"=c(sample(1:10,1000,r=T)),
                   "Size"=c(sample(0:1,1000,r=T)))
```

I work in the school district and am tasked with knowing how many Students are likely to progress in the system. I am given data1 which is historical information about proportions of students who Repeat grade, Advance to next grade, or GoBack to previous grade.

Then I also am given data2 which has in it current student enrollees.

My wish is to take a make a random category distribution for sampling based on data1 so every Student in data2 either Repeat, Advance, or GoBack. My wish is to match Student from data2 based on 'Grade' and Size' in data2 to data1 to know there chance of "Repeat", "Advance", "GoBack". Based on this it takes a random number to determine if the Student is assigned "Repeat", "Advance", "GoBack"

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your question is.. Are we talking about some sort of approximate bayesian computation? Maybe this question is better suited for [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) stackoverflows statistics forum?

Comment: @dario not quite thank you so very much. the idea is basically to draw a random number based on data1 and then that number determines what happens to the 'Student' in data2

Comment: Still struggling to understand what you are asking. But maybe it would help you to look into `sample`, which we can use to draw a random sample from a pool? Or, that's the best I could understand the question, we could calculate the proportion of `Repeat` etc. for each `Grade` - `Size` combination in `data1` and join this with `data2` (no random sampling with this solution though... )

Comment: @dario it is like a Markov Chain Simulation where you run the Students through the proportions to see where they will end up in the next years..

Comment: @dario i sincerely apologize if this is not appropriate but i wonder if you are open to a short conversation about this. i have dedicated funds for these types of consults. if this is not appropriate to ask i do indeed apologize.

Comment: Not sure how much help I can offer, but I started a chat room. You should have gotten a notification

Comment: @dario thank you so much. I didn't realize that was a feature of this platform. I am currently in the chat room.